# Close browser tab without javascript

Tags: web, cross-browser, http-headers, browser

I want to know if there are any ways to close a tab/browser by pressing a button inside a web page when JavaScript is disabled.

I might think that there are some header(request/response) params in http response that could be set on server side and browser can read these params and close the tab/browser?

If any of this make any sense please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, it's not possible.** There's only Javascript's `window.close()` which the browser may or may not follow.

Answer (score 0):

No, not that I'm aware of.  Javascript is pretty much the only way to ask the browser to close a tab/window.